# Subscription Growth Rate Model?

Tags: finance, economic-growth

Can someone provide a formula (or set of formulas) for growth models for subscription based businesses?  I've looked, but could only find general references about this business model -- no formulas.

I could probably re-purpose a growth formula and model churn (and other parameters) by adjusting the growth rate, but I was hoping for something tailored to a subscription based business.

Comment: You could make this accessible to a broader audience of potential answerers by highlighting what special features of subscription based businesses make make conventional growth models unsuitable and defining or citing those growth models in question.